# Formatting a number as Rankings as a variable in R

Tags: ranking

I am rather stuck.

I have included rankings as a variable for my dissertation, but hit a roadblock as I don't know how to treat the variable.

For instance:

- Airport Ranking

SIN     1
AUH     38
HKG     2
DXB     30

Since R treats this as an integer which operates on an ascending order basis, it will give AUH added importance since the number is larger than SIN.

I am not sure what I coding or package I need to do to ensure that R acknowledges the importance by descending order instead.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it simply a matter of sorting in descending order? If so, it's just an option on the sort:

```
airports_sorted <- airports[order(-airport_ranking),]
```

Of course, if there are multiple columns to sort by (as there often is) you would include those columns as well, in order. For example, if you have date (sorted ascending) and then rank (descending):

```
airports_sorted <- airports[order(date, -airport_ranking),]
```

Comment: Hi I tried that last night but realised it's not what I need. 

I should have been clearer last night as my work is a panel data so the data frame mixes two years of ranking. I did this option, and also rank(-airport_ranking), the whole variable went off kilter both times.

Comment: Edited the above to reflect that - is it clearer now?

Comment: Thanks! Yea I have a minor issue to solve now given that my R2 for my model is a paltry 0.08...